# How to add location path to Mysql DB with using Multer in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, multer

I'm new in Node.JS development. Recently I've struggling that problem: I want to upload photo to in "/uploads" directory in my project. I've added photo alone. But when its come to adding photo server and save its location path with photos owner id and description to Mysql DB I didn't make it.  I know that Multer only accept multipart-form data.

Here is my Node.Js code

```
var models = require('../../models');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var multer = require('multer');

var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit:'50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true, limit:'50mb'}));

const uuidv1 = require('uuid/v1');
var owner_id;
var description;

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'uploads/')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        const photo_id = uuidv1();
        cb(null, photo_id + '.jpg');
        addPhotoToDb(photo_id,owner_id,description);
    }
});

function addPhotoToDb(photo_id,owner_id,description) {
    models.PHOTOS.create({
        photo_id: photo_id,
        description: description,
        owner_id: owner_id,
        location_path: 'uploads/' + photo_id + '.jpg'
    })
}

var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('photo');

router.post('/upload', function (req, res) {
    //This part is problematic I tried so many things        
    //owner_id=req.files
    //description=req.files
    upload(req, res, function (err) {
        if (err) {
        }

        res.json({
            success: true,
            message: 'Image uploaded!'
        });
    })
});

module.exports = router;
```

Also in Postman I'm sending request like that:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/04Qz1.png

Answer (score 0):

In your screenshot you show the "body" tab. In the left there is the "headers" tab. Click on it and check that you have the content-type set to "multipart/form-data" because multer won't process any data that aren't on this content type.

Comment: The other strange fact when I choose multipart/form-data there is nothing happens. When I choose nothing content-type it works.  https://i.imgur.com/83QSjKg.png

Comment: Maybe it depends on the version of postman, but what you can check for sure is to console log what the value of req.headers['content-type'] is after the callback of the function upload when you put nothing as "content-type".